# file inclusion in c

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm not a  programmer sorry if the question is lame . If it is out of context direct me to the proper link...

If I have a header file say "file.h" and I have several functions declared in it. Apart from giving definition in "file.c" is there any way so that i can use different .c files for different functions so that header file remain file.h(which has all the corresponding functions) . 
i'm using code blocks .

any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question,  yes, you can, [here is an article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OneBigHeaderFile) that talks about it.

If you have a header file titled `header.h` and wish to have it include functions contained in `function.c` as well as from another library you simply need to do the following
**in header.h:**

```
#include "header.c"
#include <other.h>
```

Where, `other.h` is a functional header file containing your other functions.

---

***N.B.: This part of the answer refers to a section of the question that the OP removed.***

For your next question, it seems like your function declaration of `getNode` does not match how you are trying to implement it. (created as void function, but are calling it with an integer parameter). To fix your problem, I would start by sorting that out.

Comment: i cant figure out the concept... here is the main file  of my prog

Comment: Which concept? You had two questions... :P

Comment: in main i have included header.h which has function diff() and in header.h i gave diff() prototype and in header.c i have diff() definition if i want to have one more function prototype in header.h say diffDiff() and i want diffDiff() function definition in say diffDiff.h file how i can i achieve my goal

Comment: In your `header.h`, use `#include "header.c"` like you always do, and you can also include the other `.h` file which contains your other function as `#include <diffDiff.h>`... Where `diffDiff.h` is already setup with respect to `diffDiff.c`.

Answer (score 3):

[*NB: this part of the answer refers to the source code the OP deleted from his question...*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10517419/1)

You declare `getNode` as taking a single `int` argument and returning a pointer to a `node`. Yet you define `getNode` as taking no arguments and returning a pointer to a `node`.

You either need to improve your declaration or definition, and given your usage of `getNode`, I would improve your definition:

```
node* getNode(int data)
{
    node* temp=new node;
    temp->data = data; // <- use the argument
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right==NULL;
    temp->next==NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

---

As for the new question, header files are just chunks of source include by virtue of the preprocessor.

*By convention* you can use this to declare global variables, functions, and data structures. However, you must take care to ensure these declarations make sense and are in sync with the rest of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition for getNode as defined in treelib.h has an argument. Your implementation of getNode in treelib.cpp does not. So in treelib.h it is defined as "node* getNode(int);" but in treelib.cpp you've implemented it as "node* getNode()". The two are not the same. Change the version in treenode.cpp to match the definition in the header fine and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Header files are usually used to declare structures / classes, constants, function prototypes, that kind of stuff. But there's **no relation** between a header file and a source file other than the meaning you give to them; there is no such thing as "one header file per source file" or anything like that.

You can split your code as you wish. `file.h` doesn't necessarily means that there should be a `file.cpp` file anywhere. It's just convention.

Regarding your issue, you just have wrongly implemented your function (you are missing a parameter in your source file.)

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Yes, just use a different implementation file for each function and then link them.

In fact this is a good way of breaking up code into separate compilation units. It not only makes it easier to find the relevant code but can also reduce the size of your executable if some of the functions are never referenced.

Q2: You haven't defined the function `getNode(int)` but rather `getNode( )`